# Find Indices Where NumPy Int Array Value Matches Its Index Position

Tags: python, numpy

I have a long array of integers and I'd like to find all of the array indices where the array value matches the index position. Here is the solution that I came up with:

```
import numpy as np

def find_index_value_match(a):
    return a == np.arange(len(a))


a = np.array([0,1,4,4,4,0,7,9,2,3])
find_index_value_match(a)

# array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False])
```

For larger arrays (n > 100_000_000) where this function might be called repeatedly, I was wondering if there's a faster way that wouldn't require creating a new array via `np.arange`.

Comment: Maybe `[idx == val for idx, val in enumerate(a)]`?

Comment: I would have done the same, unless having a dedicated low-level numpy function I would expect this to be the fastest method.

Comment: note, that `a == np.arange(len(a))` is fast enough, and about (more than) 2 times faster than `[idx == val for idx, val in enumerate(a)]`